# NSIS Script - Digitally Signing Windows Installer

Tags: exe, nsis, code-signing

I am new to the implementation of NSIS where i would like to create a windows installer file and digitally sign it immediately via NSIS Script file. I am able to create the windows installer using the .nsi script file by executing the "makensis" command in the windows command prompt window.

When i tried to digitally sign the newly created windows installer file via NSIS script, it is showing the message in the console as successfully signed. But I found that the file is not getting signed via NSIS script file. I am using the following command to sign the application in the "Installer" section of script file

**!system 'cmd.exe /C "signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /a /f /path/to/pfx /p password /t "timestampurl" /path/to/installer/file"'**

I tried executing the command directly in the windows command prompt and the file is getting digitally signed whereas it is not getting signed via NSIS script.

Can you please suggest me the process of digitally signing the windows installer immediately after creating it?

Thanks and Regards
Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!system` executes too early, the .exe is not fully formed and should not be modified.

Use `!finalize` and `!uninstfinalize`.

Comment: I have added a section at the end of the NSIS script file and used the !finalize command to sign the installer file. I have compiled the script and able to sign the windows installer.